# Pagination div is not showing

Tags: javascript, css, html, coding-style

I am trying to show pages numbers for my results. When I see my div in developer tools, all of them are getting values. But it is not showing in the actual UI. I want to show in the bottom and pages and in fixed position.

HTML:

```
$(".pagination").Paginate_Custom({
            itemToPaginate : ".results"
        });
```

CSS:

```
.pagination {
    background-color: #C8FAC3;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width:100px;
    margin:0px auto;
    position: fixed;
}

.pagination li{
    float:center;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #C8FAC3;
    background-color: #C8FAC3;
    color:white;    
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:black;
}

.pagination ul{
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;

}

.pagination li:hover{
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove your

```
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
```

and add this

```
.pagination li{
    float:center;

    border: 1px solid #C8FAC3;
    background-color: #C8FAC3;
    color:white;    
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:black;
}
```

example

```css
.pagination {
    background-color: #C8FAC3;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width:100px;
    margin:0px auto;
    position: fixed;
}

.pagination li{
    float:center;
   
    border: 1px solid #C8FAC3;
    background-color: #C8FAC3;
    color:white;    
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:black;
}

.pagination ul{
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;

}

.pagination li:hover{
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Okay. Also, how do I make it display when user hits submit button in their search field.